# Counting the occurrences of a character in each element of a list

Tags: python, list, parity

```
     lst = ['10010001','01101001']
```

I need to count the number of times the number '1' appears in each element

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? What's your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
for element in lst:
    print element.count("1")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lst = ['10010001','01101001']
>>> [l.count('1') for l in lst]
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from collections import Counter
num_of_1s = [Counter(item)['1'] for item in lst]
```